# Postgresql Select rows where column = array

Tags: postgresql

This is a summary of what I am trying to do:

```
$array[0] = 1;
$array[1] = 2;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_id = $array"
```

Obviously, there are some syntax issues, but this is what I want to do, and I haven't found anything yet that shows how to do it.

Currently, my plan is to do something along these lines:

```
foreach($idList as $is)
    $where .= 'some_id=' . $id . ' OR';
endforeach

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE " . $where;
```

So is there support in PostgreSQL to use an array to search, or do I have to do something similar to my solution?

Answer (score 274, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   some_id = ANY(ARRAY[1, 2])
```

or `ANSI`-compatible:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   some_id IN (1, 2)
```

The `ANY` syntax is preferred because the array as a whole can be passed in a bound variable:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   some_id = ANY(?::INT[])
```

You would need to pass a string representation of the array: `{1,2}`

Comment: Thanks, that works!  What I ended up doing was:
".. some_id = ANY(ARRAY[" . implode(",", $id_array) . "])"

Comment: Hello SQL inject with the above comment... (implode php into a sql query)

Comment: the following should work better:
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   some_id = ANY(unnest(?::INT[]))

Comment: @WhiteWolfza: why do you think it would work better?

Comment: This doesn't seem to preserve the returning order defined by array input. i.e.
`select id from users where id in (2, 1)` and `select id from users where id in (1, 2)` always return in the same order: `1, 2`. How do I return `2, 1` in the first query?

Comment: @yiwen: it's a good question which is outside the scope of this one. Please post it as a separate question and I'll give you the answer there.

Comment: @Quassnoi good call, thanks. The question link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62182218/198616

Answer (score 7):

For dynamic SQL use:

`'IN(' ||array_to_string(some_array, ',')||')'`

### Example

```
DO LANGUAGE PLPGSQL $$

DECLARE
    some_array bigint[];
    sql_statement text;

BEGIN

    SELECT array[1, 2] INTO some_array;
    RAISE NOTICE '%', some_array;

    sql_statement := 'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column IN(' ||array_to_string(some_array, ',')||')';
    RAISE NOTICE '%', sql_statement;

END;

$$;
```

Result:

`NOTICE:  {1,2}
NOTICE:  SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column IN(1,2)`

Comment: i don't think = IN is proper syntax

Comment: @FlavorScape, oh my -- fixed! Althogh, it did run perfectly (ofc I test an example I post...), but that definetely looks better without the "="

Comment: definitely fails with PostgreSQL driver

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I needed to work with a column that has the data, so using IN() didn't work.
Thanks to @Quassnoi for his examples.
Here is my solution:

```
SELECT column(s) FROM table WHERE expr|column = ANY(STRING_TO_ARRAY(column,',')::INT[])
```

I spent almost 6 hours before I stumble on the post.

Answer (score 3):

```
   $array[0] = 1;
   $array[2] = 2;
   $arrayTxt = implode( ',', $array);
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_id in ($arrayTxt)"
```

Comment: You also need to check input data:
$nums = array();
foreach ($array as $a)
 if (is_numeric($a))
  $nums [] = $a;